# What exactly is Part 450 and how will it "streamline the regulatory process for companies requesting both launch and spacecraft reentry licenses"?

Tags: launch, united-states, regulatory, government, faa

CNBC's [Astra shares drop 14% after rocket launch attempt aborted and postponed](https://www.cnbc.com/2022/02/07/watch-rocket-builder-astra-launch-first-florida-mission-for-nasa.html) says:

> Notably, for this launch Astra received the first Federal Aviation Administration license under Part 450 – a new space industry framework designed to streamline the regulatory process for companies requesting both launch and spacecraft reentry licenses. Astra said the FAA approval process took about three months. This latest development will “make it easier for Astra to launch at a higher frequency out of more launch sites in the United States,” the company said.

Certainly "a new space industry framework designed to streamline the regulatory process" sounds encouraging. Does this only apply to the FAA part of "both launch and spacecraft reentry licenses" or does it integrate interaction with more than one US federal agency?

---

Potentially related:

- [How are satellites made "demisable" and what else do recent FAA documents tell us about SpaceX's plans for StarLink satellites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35002/12102)
- [Why do Space X starship launches need permission from the FAA?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49891/12102)